# Hide certain text that displays in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have a conditional statement that is bound to my gridview now that will check the sql data that is passed and if it there is a certain phrase then the gridview cell will turn pink. But if the text is not there then it will turn green.

Here is the statement I have so far:

```
  if (dataItem != null)
            {
                var label = dataItem["Client"].FindControl("ClientLabel") as Label;
                if (label != null)
                {
                    var item = dataItem;
                    var text = label.Text;

                    if (text == "Complete") 
                    {
                        item["ClientServer"].BackColor = Color.Lime;

                    }
                    else if (text != "Complete") 
                    {
                        item["ClientServer"].BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                    }
                }
```

So this works and will turn the cell green or pink depending on the text, but is there a way to hide the word "complete" and still turn the cell the correct color?

Comment: You want to hide the word "Complete" in your source code?  Or you don't want to hard code that value?  Try and ask your question in a different way.

Comment: @NickDeVore, I just want to hide the word complete. The user will manually enter this in the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question, that contains good examples on the following link:

[Getting value from a cell from a gridview on RowDataBound event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121722/getting-value-from-a-cell-from-a-gridview-on-rowdatabound-event)

```
 protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Contains("Complete"))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
            }
        }
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

How about clearing out the text property of the item (setting its sub-item text to null)? And if you eventually need it in the future you could store it in a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this method

```
Label label = dataItem["Client"].FindControl("ClientLabel") as Label;

if (text == "Complete") 
{
    item["ClientServer"].BackColor = Color.Lime;
    lable.visible = false;
}
```